# VBA finding whether a value exists in certain cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find if a value exists only in these particular cells. I've cobbled together the code from various sources and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
Resources = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,A4,A6,A8,A10")
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Resources, 0), ">0")
```

I seem to get various errors depending on what `Dim` I set for the `Resources` variable and I'm not exactly sure what the `, 0` is for?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: add `Set` before `Resources variable` in this way: `Set Resources = ...` and be sure that it's declared as `Range type` in this way: `Dim Resources as range`. What will happen?

Comment: Also COUNTIF cannot have noncontiguous ranges

Comment: @KazJaw this was my original set up, the error I get is `Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the CountIf property of the WorksheetFunction Class`. Which I guess relates to @SiddharthRout comment? Any suggestions?

Comment: I think @SiddharthRout is right. You will have additional error in `CountIf function` which you will improve in this way: `...CountIf(Resources, ">0")`. But first make the range continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Resources As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim n As Long

    Set Resources = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,A4,A6,A8,A10")

    For Each aCell In Resources
        If aCell.Value > 0 Then n = n + 1
    Next

    MsgBox n
End Sub
```